# How to launch windows applications from a website

Tags: web, windows

I want to know if it's possible to launch windows applications from a website. If it is possible, how? Sort of like battlelog for battlefield, when a button is pushed it opens an application.

Edit: This is for personal use

Comment: There is no real way to open a program on a client computer from a website without asking the client to relax their javascript settings significantly.

Comment: If you know how to do it with a relaxed javascript settings I'm willing to do that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Make each button be a link to download a company template file for the given application. For example, the "Excel" button would download and the user should be prompted to open it with Excel.

For instance, try clicking one of the links here:

http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=template+filetype:xls

Linking to static files on the web server should be sufficient, so long as your server sends the correct MIME-Type or Content-Type.
HOPE it helps!

Comment: This wouldn't take into account if I use another program like open office to open excel files.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this thread.](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?667051-Javascript-to-open-an-application) it should point you in the right direction. In short you can do this in IE using ActiveX objects. But I must warn you that it is a [very bad idea](http://www.daaq.net/old/javascript/index.php?page=what+js+cannot+do&parent=javascript+basics)